# Can I use field in a document to build my query while I'm running the query without aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find all points within a certain user supplied distance. I'm using the query:

```
{
    loc: {
        $nearSphere: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [45, 55]
            },
            $maxDistance: 5000
        }
    }
}
```

This works and is fine, except the $maxDistance field should be a variable and is actually configured on the document itself. Is there anyway with the following document structure that I could substitute 'distance' into the 'maxDistance' field during my query?

```
{
    "_id": "SUB",
    "name": "Test Restaurant",
    "description": "One of the healthiest restaurants in 'Murica",
    "minOrder": { "$numberDouble": "10.99" },
    "deliveryCost": { "$numberInt": "0" },
    "rating": { "$numberInt": "5" },
    "displayOffer": "",
    "category": "CHICKEN",
    "loc": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [{ "$numberDouble": "25.197466454320292" }, { "$numberDouble": "55.27390875087894" }] },
    "distance": { "$numberInt": "5" }
}
```

If not would I have to use an aggregation pipeline to facilitate this and if so how would I do it as efficiently as possible considering I want to iterate over every value in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$geoNear` in an aggregation pipeline to calculate the distance and store it in a distance field. Then, `$match` with calculated distance less than or equal to the `distance` field.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
          45,
          55
        ]
      },
      "distanceField": "distCalculated"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $lte: [
          "$distCalculated",
          "$distance"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2HJfULRIaWj)